# How is this a valid sentence without the word "creates" in it?

Tags: grammaticality

How is this sentence valid?

> Second, globalization doesn’t create a convergent, but a divergent economy.

Shouldn't it be "but it **creates** a divergent economy"? If this is a valid sentence, and if so, what is this writing style called?

Comment: Second, globalization creates not a convergent, but a divergent economy.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is perfectly valid: the object is 'economy', not 'convergent', which is an adjective.